is anyone have SpongeBobSun:mCalendarView .aar and shodgson:uareu .aar?
i need to rebuild my project.. but there's an error
build.gradle (root)
implementation 'sun.bob:mcalendarview:1.0.0'

implementation 'asia.kanopi.tools:fingerscan:0.1'

but now it says error :
`
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.SpongeBobSun:mCalendarView:master
and the asia.kanopi
`
i tried to clone the project in github but i can't build it on my windows. (hopefully i can get the .aar
maybe anyone can give me the .aar or .jar file to include it in my libs ?
i'll sett the build.gradle (root)
`implementation(name: 'mcalendarview-v1.0.0', ext: 'aar')

implementation(name: 'asia.kanopi.tools-v0.1', ext: 'aar')`

